# Add new distance function to matlab nctool

Tags: matlab, distance

How can I have add the jaccard distance measure in nctool
I have added Jacdist.m file to the following path

```
MATLAB\R2008b\toolbox\nnet\nnet\nndistance
```

Jacdist.m source code

```
function d = jacdist(pos)
%JACCARD Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here
fn = mfilename;
if (nargin < 1), error('NNET:Arguments','Not enough arguments.'); end
if ischar(pos)
  switch(pos)
    case 'name'
      d = 'Jaccard Distance';
    otherwise, error('NNET:Arguments',['Unrecognized code: ''' pos ''''])
  end
  return
end

[dims,s] = size(pos);
d = zeros(s,s);
for i=1:s
  for j=1:(i-1)
    d(i,j) = pdist([pos(:,i) pos(:,j)],'jaccard');
  end
end
d = min(d(i,:));
```

Then added new distance function name to newsom.m at following path

```
MATLAB\R2008b\toolbox\nnet\nnet\nnnetwork
```

But clustering is not performed correctly

Comment: Maybe you'd have luck asking at their mailing lidt [right here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/nctoolbox).

Comment: @cimrg.joe That's a completely different thing. The question refers to Neural Network Toolbox from MathWorks. Your link is to nctoolbox, a third-party toolbox for working with NetCDF data.